# How can I have an ECL logic input for a CMOS logic gate

Tags: digital-logic, bjt, logic-gates, cmos, logic-level

I'm working on a triggering system that uses a comparator to check if the signal is below a threshold value. I found a great comparator for the job, except its output is ECL logic. I wanted to use the output of the comparator as one of the inputs for the logic control circuitry that follows it, which uses CMOS logic family gates. How can make those work together? Is there a way of converting the signal? Would they work fine without any extra steps?

Comment: There are ECL-CMOS (or at least TTL) logic converters. But it would probably be  cheaper to just find a comparator with CMOS output. If you chose this comparator because it has faster response than ones available with CMOS/o.d. output, consider what that means about the likely performance of whatever CMOS load you're driving with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the ECL is below ground, and the CMOS above ground, consider this common-base converter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhGi60.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>